# Cómo puedo darle datos a mis atributos mediante csv en Python?

Tags: python, poo, csv, diseño-de-clases

Estoy haciendo un programa de vacunación (con pocos datos) con dos clases, dosis y persona, estoy metiendo los datos mediante un archivo CSV pero no sé cómo hacer que me lea los datos de las vacunas vinculados a la persona. (lo que aparece debajo de las primeras lineas del CSV)

CSV

```
cc, 13384485, Cañas Palomino, Luis Alfonso, 25-05-1982
30-06-2021, sinovac, 04054, Colsubsidio, Mariana Bello
15-01-2011, sinovac, 04055, Colsubsidio, Beatriz Benjuema

ce, 97543423, Cruz Contreras, Luis Armando, 12-12-1988
13-02-2022, sputnik, 15011, Colsubsidio, Luisa Rojas

ti, 11345683, Moreno Mora, Ana Maria, 28-03-2006
22-09-2021, astrazeneca, 04504, Hospital Santa Clara, Mercedes Cano
15-03-2022, pfizer, 04055, Hospital Santa Clara, Beatriz Rojas

cc, 2584856, Padilla Gomez, Juan Leonardo, 17-11-1972
22-05-2021, Jansen, A4665, Hospital Santa Clara, Mercedes Cano
03-12-2021 Moderna, 87455, Hospital Santa Clara, Beatriz Roa
07-04-2022, pfizer, C9283, Hospital el Tunal, Jorge Pelaez
```

Ahora seguimos con clase persona

```
import re
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, persona_info):
        match_obj = re.match(r'(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)', persona_info)
        self.id_tipo = match_obj.group(1).strip()
        self.id = match_obj.group(2).strip()
        self.apellido = match_obj.group(3).strip()
        self.nombre = match_obj.group(4).strip()
        self.fechaNacimiento = match_obj.group(5).strip()

    def __str__(self):
        return '<' + self.id + '' + self.apellido + '' + self.nombre + '' + self.fechaNacimiento + '>'
```

Luego people

```
    from persona import Persona

class People:
    def __init__(self, people_info):
        self._people_info = people_info
        self._people = []
    def makepeople(self):
        for record in self._people_info:
            p = Persona(record)
            self._people.append(p)
```

Luego peopleReader

```
class PeopleReader:
def __init__(self, filename):
    self._filename = filename

def read_people(self):
    lst = []
    with open(self._filename) as my_file:
        info=''
        for line in my_file:
            info = ''
            for line in my_file:
                if line.isspace():
                    lst.append(info)
                    info = ''
                else:
                    info = info + line
    return lst
```

Y por último driver (acá se supone que ejecuto para que me muestre las personas, y ejecuta, pero no me muestra nada- el CSV se llama registraduria)

```
from peopleReader import PeopleReader
from people import People

reader = PeopleReader("registraduria.txt")
lst = reader.read_people()

population = People(lst)
population.makepeople()
for p in population._people:
    print(p)
```

Comment: A mi me muestra en consola 3 lineas. Segura que no solucionaste el problema mientras hacías tu pregunta?

Comment: Dante, me podrías mostrar por favor qué te sale?

Comment: Por supuesto! `<sinovac04054ColsubsidioMariana Bello>
<97543423Cruz ContrerasLuis Armando12-12-1988>
<11345683Moreno MoraAna Maria28-03-2006>`

Comment: No me sale en visual pero sí en otro editor de código, muchas gracias, Dante. La verdad soy Amateur en esto... pero tengo otra pregunta, si te das cuenta, debajo de esos datos en el CSV hay datos de vacuna. ¿Cómo hago para que me lea también esos datos vinculados a mis personas? :(, llevo unas 6 hrs sacando eso y está tenaz. No sé si duplico el mismo código que hice con personas

Comment: ¿Qué son esas líneas que comienzan con "cc", "ce", "ti", etc.?

Comment: De nada! Si escribes otra pregunta, demostrando que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda (poniendo una lista de algunos de los links que visitaste o un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) puede que te de una respuesta.

Comment: @CandidMoe Hola! Es el tipo de identificación del paciente... cédula de ciudadanía, extranjería, tarjeta de identidad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perdona los nombres de los campos; puedes renombrarlos como sea más apropiado]

Mirando tu código lo he simplificado a dos clases, Persona y Vacuna.

La clase Vacuna guarda los datos de una vacunación en particular.

```
class Vacuna:
    def __init__(self, fecha, vacuna, serie, local, nombre):
        self.fecha = fecha
        self.vacuna = vacuna
        self.serie = serie
        self.local = local
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.fecha} {self.vacuna} {self.serie} {self.local} {self.nombre}"
```

La clase Persona tiene los datos de la persona y una lista de sus vacunas:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, id_tipo, id, apellido, nombre, nac):
        self.id_tipo = id_tipo
        self.id = id
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.nac = nac
        self.vacunas = []

    def agregar_vacuna(self, vacuna):
        self.vacunas.append(vacuna)

    def __str__(self):
        lineas = [f"Persona: {self.id}, {self.apellido}, {self.nombre}:"]
        for vac in self.vacunas:
            lineas.append(f" - {vac}")
        return '\n'.join(lineas)
```

Con eso el proceso es simple. Tengo una lista de personas llamada `gentes`, a la que voy agregando las personas que encuentro:

```
gentes = []
with open("vacunas.txt", "r") as vacunas:

    for linea in vacunas:
        if linea[0].isalpha():
            id_tipo, id, apellido, nombre, nac = linea.strip().split(",")
            persona = Persona(id_tipo, id, apellido, nombre, nac)
            gentes.append(persona)
        elif linea[0].isnumeric():
            fecha, id_vacuna, serie, local, nombre = linea.strip().split(",")
            vacuna = Vacuna(fecha, id_vacuna, serie, local, nombre)
            persona.agregar_vacuna(vacuna)

for persona in gentes:
    print(persona)
```

produce:

```
Persona:  13384485,  Cañas Palomino,  Luis Alfonso:
 - 30-06-2021  sinovac  04054  Colsubsidio  Mariana Bello
 - 15-01-2011  sinovac  04055  Colsubsidio  Beatriz Benjuema
Persona:  97543423,  Cruz Contreras,  Luis Armando:
 - 13-02-2022  sputnik  15011  Colsubsidio  Luisa Rojas
Persona:  11345683,  Moreno Mora,  Ana Maria:
 - 22-09-2021  astrazeneca  04504  Hospital Santa Clara  Mercedes Cano
 - 15-03-2022  pfizer  04055  Hospital Santa Clara  Beatriz Rojas
Persona:  2584856,  Padilla Gomez,  Juan Leonardo:
 - 22-05-2021  Jansen  A4665  Hospital Santa Clara  Mercedes Cano
 - 03-12-2021  Moderna  87455  Hospital Santa Clara  Beatriz Roa
 - 07-04-2022  pfizer  C9283  Hospital el Tunal  Jorge Pelaez

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edición**

Corregi el método `Persona.__str__()`; faltaban los "self." para acceder a los campos propios de la persona.

Comment: Wow... creéme que si pudiera invitarte a un café, lo haría. Te agradezco como no te lo imaginas! Creo que me estaba enredando mucho

Comment: @MelanieAlejandraSolanoOrozc sinceramente, yo elegiría cambiarle el formato al csv (si es que es posible) de tal forma que se pueda saber con más certeza si se trata de una persona o una vacuna (por ejemplo que uno de los campos diga la cantidad de vacunas, o un string que diga "persona" o "vacuna" dependiendo el caso). Por que la verdad, que pasaría si se trata de una persona pero el primer caracter es un numero igualmente? Creería que es una vacuna.

Comment: Los datos de una persona más sus vacunas están separados por una línea en blanco de otras personas. Se puede detectar esa línea para saber donde empieza cada grupo.

Comment: No me convence esa separación. Que pasaría si alguien piensa que es decorativa y la saca?